# Image disappears in Microsoft Print to Pdf

Tags: pdf, printing, pdf-generation, imaging

I've developed a popup window and I use the body `onload='window.print()'` function to print the document, and then I choose the printer `Microsoft Print to Pdf`, which produces a PDF.  However, the main logo I have at the top of the document goes missing.  I have another website which uses the same approach with a different logo and that works fine.

I have attached the problematic logo below:

[image: Problematic logo]

The image is a PNG. I originally used a transparent background, but I thought that maybe the PDF converter thinks the ratio of dark to light is too high and hides it, so I changed the background to white to increase the lightness ratio, but to no avail.

Is there something else I can do to force the logo to appear without the user having to tweak print configurations?

Comment: I've tried using jpg instead, and also increasing the amount of white wrapping the image

Comment: Providing a minimal example document might help getting answers. Also saying what system OS, browser, you use.